# Why I have to use a Semi-colon before my code?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have this code:

```
this.userService.register(value).pipe(
    finalize(() => this.isRequesting = false)
).subscribe(
    () => this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { brandNew: true, email: value.email } }),
    (error: any) => this.errors = error
);
```

It doesn't work until I put a semicolon before `this.router`:

```
() => ; this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { brandNew: true, email: value.email } }),
```

It is really weird, why should this be happening? It has nothing to do with `this.router.navigate` because if I replace it by an alert like this `alert('alert')` it doesn't work again until I put a semi-colon before it. It seems really odd to me, would you please help me with this?

Also the error that it throws is just a simple `[object Object]` which makes me more confused, I have also looked at this question but changing the browser to chrome had no effect: [Resolver Emitting Error ` ERROR Error: "[object Object]" `](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041301/resolver-emitting-error-error-error-object-object)

This is the register method of the userservice:

```
register(userRegistration: UserRegistration): Observable<{}> {

  let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

  return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "/account", userRegistration, { headers: headers });
}
```

Comment: Can you provide minimal reproduction on stackblitz. The current code seems to be right.

Comment: @SachinGupta No. It doesn't right, I have tested it in different ways, it really doesn't work for me until I put a semi-colon before that line!

Comment: You've likely got a bug somewhere higher up.

Comment: Please provide a stackblitz and we can learn more about it.

Comment: @Liam If so, why the bug somewhere higher up, should be disappeared by putting the semi-colon here?

Comment: Because the semi colon will end the line. Everyone else is right, we need a [MCVE here to help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) without this we're guessing. This is why [you should put semi colons on every line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript)